# Wordpress : Why Plugin name is unique?

Tags: wordpress

I am new in wordpress. I have read lots of about the plugin creation and thier steps. Can any body explain me why the plugin name is unique? I have read that for avoiding conflict keep plugin name unique. My question is if I have created different or unique shortcode then whats the problem?

Answer (score 2):

In case you publish it, it needs a unique name to display on the WordPress page (or wherever).

How would a regular user know which plugin is the right one if both have the same name? Less computer-savvy users wouldn't be able to check for the plugin code to differentiate them.

Also, the plugin files are named after the plugin name itself. And Wordpress uses this information internally. If two plugins that happen to have the same name were installed under the same Wordpress website, there might be conflicts on Wordpress representation.

Answer (score 0):

A WordPress plugin identified on WordPress.org by its name only. So if plugin name is not unique, even on a local computer for testing, plugin might be overridden automatically by the next update from by a developer with the same app name published in wordpress.org/plugins/.

What happens when you upload manually a none unique name plugin to your WordPress blog? I guess it will be damaged or hacked by anyone who publishes plugin with the same name. That is why not only the name must be unique but you also have to publish it on wordpress.org/plugins/ to prevent anyone change it, or else you have to disable plugin updates.